# Will chili fruit ripen if it's a bit cool?

Tags: chili

[image]

I had a bunch of chilis come in around Feb/Mar and since in Auckland NZ (Southern Hemisphere). When should I harvest? It's a very temperate climate and we only got 1 minor frost last year.

Ideally, I'd harvest once everything was big, red, and ripe but I'm guessing that everything will shut down soon. We're currently getting highs of 17-18C but will drop to ~10-13(?) in 6 weeks or so.

Answer (score 1):

In general they will keep ripening until they die...

but that one has stopped growing, you can see the stem is dried out, basically disconnected from the plant... pick that one. let the little one grow.

Take care of those aphids also, probably why the last one got cut off.

Comment: Yep, I concur. However, I should note that when refrigerated, they're less likely to ripen before they spoil than sitting out on the table or something. However, those temperatures aren't that cold (even if it would have an effect on the ripening if it were colder). They should ripen just fine. My peppers seem to ripen fine at colder temperatures than that (although, I'm not sure, but it's possible that near-freezing temperatures do delay ripening some).